# Как убрать первый символ из строки?

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная, которая содержит данные вида `%4820109928069`.
Как убрать символ процента, чтобы осталось только число?

Comment: можете использовать [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), или [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) или [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: символ `%` может быть только первым символом?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Важно:** все приведенные ниже методы **не** меняют исходную строку!

---

можете использовать [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '%4820109928069'.slice(1);
```

или [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '%4820109928069'.substr(1);
```

или [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '%4820109928069'.substring(1);
```

Если вы хотите в итоге получить не *строку* состоящую из цифр, а число, то необходимо также использовать

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = typeof '%4820109928069'.substring(1);
document.body.innerHTML +='<br/>'+ typeof parseInt('%4820109928069'.substring(1),10);
document.body.innerHTML +='<br/>'+ parseInt('%4820109928069'.substring(1),10);
```

или [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = typeof '%4820109928069'.substring(1);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br/>' + typeof parseFloat('%4820109928069'.substring(1));
document.body.innerHTML += '<br/>' + parseFloat('%4820109928069'.substring(1));
```

---

**Upd.**
Еще вариант с [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

удаляем `%` с начала строки

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '%4820109928069'.replace(/^%/,'');
```

удаляем все `%` в строке:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '%4820109%928069%'.replace(/%/g,'');
```

удаляем все не цифровые символы:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '%482s01099$280%69zxc_'.replace(/\D/g,'');
```